# Chaining 2 Strings in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I want to chain 2 strings in C. The function I use called `concat()`
First I defined something like this and it worked

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char* result = malloc (15);  
    int lengh1 =  simple_strlen (s1);
    int lengh2 =  simple_strlen (s2);
    int i=0,j;
    for ( i = 0 ;i < lengh1;i++){
        if (i!=lengh1-1)
            result[i]=s1[i];
        else{
            result[i]=s1[i];
            for ( j=i+1 ; j< lengh1+lengh2;j++){
                    result[j] = s2[j-i-1];
            }
        }
    }

return result;
}
```

But then I was asked to do it without `malloc()` so I defined something like this:

```
char* concat( char *result, const char *s2)
{  
    int lengh1 =  simple_strlen (result);
    int lengh2 =  simple_strlen (s2);
    int i=0;
    for ( i = 0 ;i < lengh2;i++){   
            result[i+lengh1]=s2[i];
    } 
    return result;
}
```

but it has segmentation fault

```
example:



   int main(int argc , char* argv[], char* envp[])
   {
          printf(concat( "hello", "world"));/*output expected "helloworld"*/

        return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] for your second example.  How is this function called?

Comment: I assume `result` was not initialized to point to anything, or it points somewhere not big enough to store your concatenated string.  But We cannot know for sure since you did not provide the MCVE.

Comment: You need to review a bit about memory and strings. Your second method causes a fault because you cannot use memory past the end of "result". Your problem is probably poorly defined because while you can say "do not use malloc", you have to have some place to put your new string.

Comment: @OldProgrammer example was added

Comment: your 'result' string doesn't have enough extra memory to accommodate characters from the 's2' string.

Comment: @srikanth_16 I know what should I do (code please)

Comment: "to do it without malloc()"  --> `concat( char *result, const char *s2)` is prone to buffer overrun.  Can code use `concat( char *result, size_t size, const char *s2)` or the like?

Comment: both example code have undefined behavior.  The first fails to allocate an extra byte of memory for the trailing NUL byte.  The second writes beyond the available memory, thereby corrupting the stack.  (another instance of undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in the `malloc` version, the space allocated for the destination string is hard coded at `15` instead of computing it as `lengh1 + lengh2 + 1`, enough space for both strings and the trailing null byte.
- you do not set the null terminator at the end of the destination string in both versions.
- in your version without `malloc`, you must provide a large enough array as the destination for `concat()`. A string constant cannot be modified. A simple solution is to pass the destination buffer and the source strings as separate arguments.

Here are modified versions:

```
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int length1 = simple_strlen(s1);
    int length2 = simple_strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(length1 + length2 + 1);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        result[i] = s1[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
        result[length1 + i] = s2[1];
    }
    result[length1 + length2] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Without `malloc()`:

```
#include <string.h>

char *concat(char *dest, const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *p = dest;
    while (*s1)
        *p++ = *s1++;
    while (*s2)
        *p++ = *s2++;
    *p = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    /* output expected "helloworld" */
    printf("%s\n", concat(buf, "hello", "world"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the prior commenters, you need to allocate memory *somewhere* to store the concatenated string.   If you are not allowed to allocate on the heap via malloc, then you can do something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
# include <string.h>
char* concat( char * result , const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int lengh1 = strlen(s1);
    int lengh2 = strlen(s2);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < lengh1; i++) {
        result[i] = s1[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < lengh2; i++) {
        result[i+ lengh1] = s2[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    char mybuffer[100];
    memset(mybuffer, 0, sizeof(mybuffer));
    printf(concat( mybuffer,"hello", "world"));/*output expected "helloworld"*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can the array be defined inside of the con concat Function?

Comment: No, you don't do that. Because memory will be allocated in stack space, which will be freed up after function call is over, which in turn results in UB.

Comment: Not really.  you could make is static

Comment: @OldProgrammer but how do we access it in the main function?

Comment: `concat()` does not write a _null character_.  Obliging the calling code to do so, like with `memset(mybuffer, 0, sizeof(mybuffer));` is a design weakness in this `concat()`.  `concat()` lacking a size parameter is akin to `gets()`.